# How to write to Hive table with static partition using PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, hadoop-partitioning

I've created a Hive table with a partition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table
(uid INT, num INT) PARTITIONED BY (dt DATE)
```

Then with PySpark, I'm having a dataframe and I've tried to write it to the Hive table like this:

```
df.write.format('hive').mode('append').partitionBy('dt').saveAsTable('my_table')
```

Running this I'm getting an exception:

> Dynamic partition strict mode requires at least one static partition column. To turn this off set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict

I then added this config:

```
hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
```

This time no exception but the table wasn't populated either!

Then I removed the above config and added this:

```
hive.exec.dynamic.partition=false
```

Also altered the code to be like:

```
df.write.format('hive').mode('append').partitionBy(dt='2022-04-29').saveAsTable('my_table')
```

This time I am getting:

> Dynamic partition is disabled. Either enable it by setting hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true or specify partition column values

The Spark job I want to run is going to have daily data, so I guess what I want is the static partition, but how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't predefined all the partitions you will need to use:

```
hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
```

Remember that hive is schema on read, and it won't automagically fix your data into partitions.  You need to inform the meta-store of the paritions.
You will need to do that manually [with one of the two commands](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/MSCK-REPAIR-HIVE-EXTERNAL-TABLES/td-p/229066):

```
alter table <db_name>.<table_name> add partition(`date`='<date_value>') location '<hdfs_location_of the specific partition>';
```

or

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE [tablename]
```

Answer (score 0):

if the table is already created, and you are using `append` mode anyway, you can use `insertInto` instead of `saveAsTable`, and you don't even need `.partitionBy('dt')`

```py
df.write.format('hive').mode('append').insertInto('my_table')
```